# disable and required not work

Tags: jquery, html

I use a stepform like [this](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-and-validation), but when I click on my next button the step pass to another without writing,

the code that I use is similar to the link but I modify some things but the function is equal, here is my code:

this is my HTML

```
<table id="tabla-orden2">
    <tr>
        <td width="52%">
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Calle</label>
            <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Escriba una calle" id="route" name="route" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">C.P.</label>
                <input maxlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="06700" id="postal_code" name="postal_code" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">No. exterior</label>
                <input type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="000" id="street_number" name="street_number" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">No. interior</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="000" id="internal_number" name="internal_number" disabled="disabled" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div class="posicion-boton-sig">
    <button class="btn btn-success nextBtn btn-lg pull-right btn-siguiente" type="button" id="siguiente">Siguiente </button>
</div>
```

here it is my script:

```
var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
allWells = $('.setup-content'),
allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn'),
allPrevBtn = $('.prevBtn'),
allcloseBtn = $('.close');
allWells.hide();

navListItems.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
    $item = $(this);

    if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
        navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-black');
        $item.addClass('btn-success');
        allWells.hide();
        $target.show();
        $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();

        if ($("hr.ln2").hasClass("cl3")) {
            $("#st-3").removeClass("btn-default3");
            $("hr.ln2").addClass("cll");
            $("a#st-2").html("<img src='/static/dashboard/img/icon/icon-ok.svg'>");
            $("p#nota").css("color", "#85c440");

        }

        if ($("hr").hasClass("ln1")) {
            $("#st-2").removeClass("btn-default3");
            $("hr.ln1").addClass("cll");
            $("hr.ln2").addClass("cl3");
            /*$("p#entrega").addClass("colorpesos");*/
            $("p#entrega").css("color", "#85c440");
            $("a.btn-circle1").html("<img src='/static/dashboard/img/icon/icon-ok.svg'>");
        }

    }
});

allcloseBtn.click(function () {
    $("#step-2").hide();
    $("#step-3").hide();
    $("#step-1").show();

    $('.pes-1').removeClass('colorpesos');
    $('.pes-2').removeClass('colorpesos');
    $('.pes-3').removeClass('colorpesos');

    $('.t-envio-9').removeClass('colorpesos');
    $('.t-envio-p').removeClass('colorpesos');

    $("#img-bici").hide();
    $("#img-moto").hide();
    $("#img-mc").hide();

    $('#entrega').css('color', '#6a706d');
    $('#nota').css('color', '#6a706d');

});

allNextBtn.click(function () {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
    nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
    curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
    isValid = true;
    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
    for (var i = 0; i < curInputs.length; i++) {
        if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid) {
            isValid = false;
            $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
        }
    }
    if (isValid)
        nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');

});
allPrevBtn.click(function () {
    var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
    curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
    prevStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().prev().children("a");
    $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");

    var nn = document.getElementById("n9-minutos");
    var prg = document.getElementById("mismo-dia");

    if (nn.className == 'btn btn-default t-envio-9 colorpesos') {
        $('.t-envio-9').removeClass('colorpesos');
        nn.disabled = true;
    } else if (prg.className == 'btn btn-default t-envio-p colorpesos') {
        $('.t-envio-p').removeClass('colorpesos');
    }

    if (prg.disabled == false) {
        prg.disabled = true;
    }
    if (nn.disabled == false) {
        nn.disabled = true;
    }

    var bicycle = document.getElementById("peso-1");
    var bike = document.getElementById("peso-2");
    var mini = document.getElementById("peso-3");

    if (bicycle.className == 'btn btn-default pes-1 colorpesos') {
        $('.pes-1').removeClass('colorpesos');
    } else if (bike.className == 'btn btn-default pes-2 colorpesos') {
        $('.pes-2').removeClass('colorpesos');
    } else if (mini.className == 'btn btn-default pes-3 colorpesos') {
        $('.pes-3').removeClass('colorpesos');
    }


    prevStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
});

$('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
//FIN FORM WIZARD
```

I want to validate the form when I click in the next button, but if the input is disabled not work the validation

Comment: If an input is disabled, validation is not done on it.

Comment: @Bamar is right, disabled doesn't trigger validation. Just change It to readonly instead

Answer (score 0):

**disabled="disabled"** input not posting so validation not consider those disabled input fields so try to use **readonly**

Comment: 's readonly don't help me, cause i have a input that is an autocomple that uses the google's api so when the person write a  address the rest of the inputs are filled with that information and if the data is wrong the person could modify that data, so when the address is selected the inputs are availables